# Trying to clone a git repo it stuck at cloning into

Tags: git, http, github, ssh, carla

I am using Windows 10 *Ver 10.0.19042 Build 19042*
, GIT *Ver 2.32*
when trying to execute the following command using git bash
`git clone --depth=1 -b carla https://github.com/CarlaUnreal/UnrealEngine.git .`
to clone the carla project it **stucks** displaying the message `cloning into '.'` forever.

sometimes it yields output Error: error writing "stdout": broken pipe
I Have tried the following solutions

- Replace the HTTPS with HTTP
- I have installed Open SSH for windows

Also, note that I have copied other repos from git using the command `git clone <git_repo>` and it **works fine**

I want to clone the repo with no issues any help ?

Comment: Try using:  git clone --depth 1 --branch carla https://github.com/CarlaUnreal/UnrealEngine.git

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the same command (Git 2.32 on Windows 10 as well)

The `--depth=1` syntax does work well, both in CMD and git bash.

If you want to test with SSH, you will have to do:

```
git clone --depth=1 -b carla git@github.com/CarlaUnreal/UnrealEngine.git .
```

(assuming you have a public key registered to your profile, considering this is a private repository)