# Cloning issues private repo with GIT BASH

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I installed git bash on windows and when I try to clone a private repo (git clone https://github.com/username/project.git) , it doesn't ask me for my username and password and just stay stuck on : "Cloning into 'project name'...

But when I try to clone public repo, I don't have any problem

Comment: May you share the output of `git clone --verbose <repo-url>`? (replace `<repo-url>` with the actual repo url)

Comment: it gets stuck on "Cloning into "projet name' ... even with --verbose option

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67880831/trying-to-clone-a-git-repo-it-stuck-at-cloning-into

Comment: apparently its just taking a long time cause my repo is huge

Comment: @guts_tribute Is it successfully cloned now?

Comment: I let it clone for an hour, it created me just the root directory of my project but nothing more ...

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but here's my solution go to control panel > Credentials Manager

Add Generic credential

network address: git:https://github.com

and your github username & password.